# Secure StringSinks

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi, crypto++

So it seems that the common way to use algorithms in Crypto++ is to use `StringSinks`, which are initiated by passing a reference to a `std::string`.

But what if you don't want to use `std::string` [because of security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683941/clearing-memory-securely-and-reallocations)? Is it possible to get the data into something like a `SecByteBlock`, or do I have to create my own sink class which targets a re-growing secure buffer string class?

Comment: Please be aware that any answers here won't fully protect your keys. They must remain in memory while they are being used. So must your data obviously, which is what you are trying to protect. So please only think of these kind of solutions as an additional protection that can be used on an already safe protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [SecByteBlockSink patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/m79y5vh6Stg/IT-w6yToDlwJ). It was posted to the Crypto++ Users group, but Wei never incorporated it into the library. There's also a wiki page on it here: [SecByteBlockSink](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SecByteBlockSink) .

```
$ cat filters.h.patch
Index: filters.h
===================================================================
--- filters.h        (revision 525)
+++ filters.h        (working copy)
@@ -10,6 +10,7 @@
 #include "queue.h"
 #include "algparam.h"
 #include <deque>
+#include <limits>

 NAMESPACE_BEGIN(CryptoPP)

@@ -805,6 +806,31 @@
                 {SourceInitialize(pumpAll,
MakeParameters("RandomNumberGeneratorPointer",
&rng)("RandomNumberStoreSize", length));}
 };

+class CRYPTOPP_DLL SecByteBlockSink : public Bufferless<Sink>
+{
+public:
+        SecByteBlockSink(SecByteBlock& sbb) : m_sbb(sbb) { }
+
+        size_t Put2(const byte *inString, size_t length, int /*messageEnd*/, bool /*blocking*/)
+        {
+                if(!inString || !length) return length;
+
+                const size_t size = m_sbb.size();
+                const size_t max = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() - size;
+
+                if(length > max)
+                        InvalidArgument("SecByteBlockSink: buffer overflow");
+
+                m_sbb.resize(size+length);
+                memcpy(m_sbb.begin()+size, inString, length);
+                
+                return 0;
+        }
+
+private:
+        SecByteBlock& m_sbb;
+};
+
 NAMESPACE_END

 #endif
```

Comment: Why is it not in the library? It seems very convenient to have it.