# Can placement new survive optimization, unlike memset?

Tags: c++, memory, optimization

So I'm really intrigued about whether or not it can survive aggressive optimization tactics employed by GCC and clang.

Considering the following example:

```
void* clean(void* pointer, std::size_t size) noexcept
{
    return new(pointer) char[size]{};
}

void doStuff()
{
    //...
    clean(pointer, size);
    //...
}
```

Can I trust it with the task of cleaning sensitive data?

Comment: You cannot trust array placement new [at all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8720425)!

Comment: @KerrekSB the example specified in that question isn't a basic type. The "y" mentioned in there is the alignment required by the given type, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @KerrekSB Just checked myself, [`clean(pointer, size);` doesn't add any overhead whatsoever aka alignment offset.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83952ed415cbd363) It would make no sense at all for there to be overhead when using an 1-byte aligned type.

Comment: I don't think you can trust *any* code you come up with yourself, you must search out a function provided for this purpose by your compiler or OS.

Comment: @MarkRansom A OS function for this purpose might be subjected to the same treatment memset gets, not to mention portability between GCC and clang is important to me.

Comment: "A OS function for this purpose might be subjected to the same treatment memset gets" No, it cannot. This is exactly the point of having such function. Compiler cannot remove it as it cannot prove abscense of side effects.

Comment: @bit2shift a compiler can't predict side effects, so there's no possible way a function call could be optimized out. As for portability, one has to hope that the same function is available in both; I don't see any way around it.

Comment: @M.M: There is no correct answer. You cannot use array placement new portably.

Comment: @KerrekSB your first comment should probably be an answer to this question then: since placement `new[]` cannot be used in the first place, the question is moot. (I guess we could say that `new(pointer) char[size]{};` causes UB because it is permitted to write more than `size` bytes).

Comment: @KerrekSB you can, goddamn it, but you need to avoid STL types on them.

Comment: @M.M with that reasoning, so does memset() cause UB.

Comment: @bit2shift please explain how memset causes UB

Comment: @M.M considering a pointer to a memory with 10 bytes, doing `memset(ptr, 0, 11);` causes UB since you're writing out-of-bounds.

Comment: @bit2shift That's right. What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: @M.M that UB is guaranteed to happen if you pass a larger size to it. But in this case, the placement new DOES NOT write extra bytes considering we're talking about a fundamental type. Not a class or struct, with or without vtables and/or an inheritance tree.

Comment: @bit2shift the C++ Standard says that `new(pointer) char[size]` writes `size + y` bytes where `y` is an unspecifed value

Comment: @bit2shift see section 5.3.4/14  . Is discussed in more detail on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720425/array-placement-new-requires-unspecified-overhead-in-the-buffer/35926866)

Comment: BTW, scrubbing secure data from memory is practically impossible in C or C++, e.g. discussions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683941/clearing-memory-securely-and-reallocations), [here](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-06-zeroing-buffers-is-insufficient.html)

Comment: @M.M Did you bother reading the [16^ answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14591969/2748628)?

Comment: @bit2shift Yep, sure did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105948/discussion-between-bit2shift-and-m-m).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think optimization can play any tricks on you here. Standard **mandates** value initialization in this case: `new(pointer) char[size]{}`, so after this call memory pointed to by `pointer` would be filled with 0.

May be compiler can optimize it if you never access the new pointer or override it before accessin (based on observability). If you want to avoid this slight possibility, you'd need to define your pointer as a pointer to `volatile`.

Comment: But after, the buffer is unused.

Comment: @Jarod42, yes, I thought about it and updated my answer.

Comment: In both scenarios I'm using this approach, the pointer either gets returned (allocation) or gets passed to a deallocation function leading to `std::free`.

Comment: @Jarod42, i think, cast to void* before placement new (to get rid of volatile) would be OK.... I think.

Comment: An optimizer is allowed to do anything that has no observable effect on the program. If it can establish that the object won't be used, and that the constructor has no side effects, then it is perfectly within its rights to skip the constructor entirely.

Comment: @SergeyA: if you remove the `volatile` for the `new` it is really useless.

Comment: @Jarod42, I am not sure about it. It is hard to say what qualifies for observable effect anymore. I honestly don't know.

Comment: @SergeyA "observable behaviour" is defined by section [intro.execution]/8 of the C++ standard

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this is an answer to your question or just a side note but you can disable optimization on that specific function using `optimize()` compiler directive

```
void* __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) clean(void* pointer, std::size_t size) {
    // unmodifiable compiler code
}
```

This will ensure your clean() function will not be optimized away