# Removing OPENSSL_cleanse from OpenSSL-1.0.1r

Tags: c++, c, xcode, linker, openssl

I found out that `OPENSSL_cleanse` wastes a lot of time in my [project](https://brute.tk). For example, if it runs for 25 seconds, *3 seconds* are wasted by `OPENSSL_cleanse`. I checked the code of this function and decided that it isn't doing anything very useful for me. I know it [fills memory with garbage data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433959/4354477) for security reasons but I don't really care about it. So I decided to place `return;` just before the start of any operations in this function.

```
void OPENSSL_cleanse(void *ptr, size_t len)
{
    return;
    // original OpenSSL code goes here
}
```

I'm using Mac OS and Xcode. I've compiled the lib and installed it in `/Users/ForceBru/Desktop/openssl` via the `--openssldir` option of the `Configure` script. I've added it to my project in `Build Settings->Link Binary With Libraries` and added include dirs in `Build Settings->Search Paths->Header Search Paths` and `Build Settings->Search Paths->Library Search Paths`.

The project compiled fine, but the time profiler still shows pretty expensive calls to `OPENSSL_cleanse`.

**Edit:** the `C` tag is because OpenSSL is written in C, and the `C++` tag is because my code is in C++. Maybe this information will be helpful.

The question is, what am I doing wrong? How do I remove the calls to `OPENSSL_cleanse`? I think this has to do with linking, because the command line includes `-lcrypto`, which means this library can actually be taken from anywhere (right?), not necessarily from `/Users/ForceBru/Desktop/openssl`.

**Edit #2:** I've edited the linker options to use the `.a` file in `/Users/ForceBru/Desktop/openssl` and removed it from `Build Settings->Link Binary With Libraries`. Still no effect.

Comment: I think you are correct, this is probably the reason. You might want to link your modified instance of openssl statically to your project (I do _not_ suggest to link a completely static binary, just the openssl library)

Comment: @Ctx, how do I do it?

Comment: Locate the correct versions of your custom openssl library libssl.a and libcrypto.a and specify these on your linker command line with full path. Drop `-lssl` and `-lcrypto` from it in turn.

Comment: @Ctx, I've done it, but it `OPENSSL_cleanse` is still there

Comment: You could check if the libcrypto.a you use indeed is your modified version with `objdump -d libcrypto.a` and see if it indeed returns without doing anything else. Otherwise something went already wrong with customizing openssl.

Comment: @Ctx, checked that and it shows that `OPENSSL_cleanse` isn't just `return`ing, but doing what it was supposed to do. I tried removing it completely and replacing its declaration with `#define OPENSSL_cleanse(a, b)` in `crypto/crypto.h`, but now when I try to link with the library, I'm getting an error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: _OPENSSL_ia32cap_P referenced from _sha1_block_data_order in libcrypto.a`. `OPENSSL_cleanse` is still there even after removing it from the code completely, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that OpenSSL has lots of assembly code generated by some Perl scripts that are located in the `crypto` directory (`*cpuid.pl`). These scripts generate assembly code for the following architectures: `alpha`, `armv4`, `ia64`, `ppc`, `s390x`, `sparc`, `x86` and `x86_64`.

When `make` runs, the appropriate script fires generating a `*cpuid.S` (where `*` is one of the architectures mentioned earlier). These files are compiled into the library and seem to override the `OPENSSL_cleanse` implemented in `crypto/mem_clr.c`.

What I had to do is to simply change the body of `OPENSSL_cleanse` to `ret` in `x86_64cpuid.pl`:

```
.globl OPENSSL_cleanse
.type OPENSSL_cleanse,\@abi-omnipotent
.align 16
OPENSSL_cleanse:
    ret
    # loads of OPENSSL assembly
.size OPENSSL_cleanse,.-OPENSSL_cleanse
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite the answer that you were looking for, but it may help you along...

---

> Removing OPENSSL_cleanse from OpenSSL-1.0.1r...
>   I checked the code of this function and decided that it isn't doing anything very useful for me...

That's probably a bad idea, but we would need to know more about your threat model. Zeroization allows you to deterministically remove sensitive material from memory.

Its also a Certification and Accreditation (C&A) item. For example, [FIPS 140-2](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/standards.html) requires zeroization even at Level 1.

Also, you can't remove `OPENSSL_cleanse` *per se* because `OPENSSL_clear_realloc`, `OPENSSL_clear_free` and friends call it.  Also see the [`OPENSSL_cleanse`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/OPENSSL_cleanse_CRYPTO_malloc.html) man page.

---

> For example, if it runs for 25 seconds, 3 seconds are wasted by OPENSSL_cleanse

OK, so this is a different problem. [OPENSSL_cleanse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26433772/608639) is kind of convoluted, and it does waste some cycles in an effort to survive the optimization pass.

If you check [Commit 380f18ed5f140e0a](http://git.openssl.org/?p=openssl.git;a=commitdiff;h=104ce8a9f02d250dd43c255eb7b8747e81b29422;hp=380f18ed5f140e0ae1b68f3ab8f4f7c395658d9e), then you will see it has been changed in OpenSSL 1.1.0 to the following. Maybe you could use it instead?

```
diff --git a/crypto/mem_clr.c b/crypto/mem_clr.c
index e6450a1..3389919 100644 (file)
--- a/crypto/mem_clr.c
+++ b/crypto/mem_clr.c
@@ -59,23 +59,16 @@
 #include <string.h>
 #include <openssl/crypto.h>

-extern unsigned char cleanse_ctr;
-unsigned char cleanse_ctr = 0;
+/*
+ * Pointer to memset is volatile so that compiler must de-reference
+ * the pointer and can't assume that it points to any function in
+ * particular (such as memset, which it then might further "optimize")
+ */
+typedef void *(*memset_t)(void *,int,size_t);
+
+static volatile memset_t memset_func = memset;

 void OPENSSL_cleanse(void *ptr, size_t len)
 {
-    unsigned char *p = ptr;
-    size_t loop = len, ctr = cleanse_ctr;
-
-    if (ptr == NULL)
-        return;
-
-    while (loop--) {
-        *(p++) = (unsigned char)ctr;
-        ctr += (17 + ((size_t)p & 0xF));
-    }
-    p = memchr(ptr, (unsigned char)ctr, len);
-    if (p)
-        ctr += (63 + (size_t)p);
-    cleanse_ctr = (unsigned char)ctr;
+    memset_func(ptr, 0, len);
 }
```

Also see [Issue 455: Reimplement non-asm OPENSSL_cleanse()](http://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/455) on OpenSSL's GitHub.

---

> How do I remove the calls to OPENSSL_cleanse?

OK, so this is a different problem. You have to locate all callers and do something with each. It looks like there's about 185 places you will need to modify things:

```
$ cd openssl
$ grep -IR _cleanse * | wc -l
     185
```

---

Instead of this:

```
void OPENSSL_cleanse(void *ptr, size_t len)
{
    return;
    // original OpenSSL code goes here
}
```

Maybe you can delete the function, and then:

```
#define OPENSSL_cleanse(x, y)
```

Then the function calls becomes a macro that simply disappears during optimization. Be sure to perform a `make clean` after changing from a function to a macro.

But I would not advise doing so.

---

> The project compiled fine, but the time profiler still shows pretty expensive calls to OPENSSL_cleanse.

My guess here is either (1) you did not perform a `make clean` after the changes to the OpenSSL library, or (2) you compiled and linked to the wrong version of the OpenSSL library. But I could be wrong on both.

You can see what your executable's runtime dependencies are with `otool -L`. Make sure its the expected one. Also keep in mind OpenSSL does not use `-install_name`.

Before you run your executable, you can set [DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) to ensure the dylib you are modifying is loaded. Also see the [dyld(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) man pages.

Comment: I provided a link to my project so you can see that I really don't care about that security reason. It's just a brute-force program, and what I need is just speed, so any time consumers must be removed. No, changing `OPENSSL_cleanse` to a macro gives linker errors due to that assembly code I was talking about in my answer. What I don't understand now, is the purpose of the function in `mem_clr.c`. Why it is here when there's assembly for it?

Comment: @ForceBru - *"What I don't understand ... the purpose of the function in mem_clr.c. Why it is here when there's assembly for it..."* - I'm not sure about that. I think I share your understanding of things, so its kind of a mystery to me, too.