# C code to clean up memory for openssl EVP_PKEY private keys

Tags: c, openssl, private-key

I'm starting learn OpenSSL programming in C/C++. An issue I encountered is, how could I safely wipe out the memory for private keys?

For example, I may have code:

```
EVP_PKEY *private_key = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey( bio, ,,,)
RSA *r = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA( private_key);
```

I'd like to wipe out private_key from memory cleanly before using EVP_PKEY_free() to free it.

I'd appreciate for helps and/or your suggestions. 
Thanks.

Comment: Will `memset(...)` work for you?

Comment: Safely clearing memory is yuite a complicated subject. It depends on the implementation how to accomplish this. Note that not only erasing the key is. Reading them and storing already is a problem, if you want to prevent other processes to e.g. read the memory.

Answer (score 5):

> `EVP_PKEY *private_key = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey( bio, ,,,)`
>
> I'd like to wipe out private_key from memory cleanly before using `EVP_PKEY_free` to free it.

OpenSSL's `EVP_PKEY_free` wipes the private key for you. You don't have to do anything special.

> `RSA *r = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA( private_key);`

The `get1` means the reference count was bumped and you effectively got your own copy of the object. A `get0` means you got a pointer to an existing object, and you should *not* call `free` on it. Because of `get1`, you must call `RSA_free` on it to ensure it gets deleted. As with `EVP_PKEY_free`, `RSA_free` will wipe the key.

Please don't call `memset`. These are opaque structures, and you have to follow a number of pointers to correctly clear the sub-objects. A lot more fields have been hidden in OpenSSL 1.1.0, so its going to be more difficult to follow the pointers (if you wanted to).  Also see [Error: “invalid use of incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}” in OpenSSL 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40549318/608639), [Visual Studio and error C2027: use of undefined type 'rsa_st' in OpenSSL 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41348281/608639), [EVP_get_cipherbyname and “undefined struct/union evp_cipher_st” in OpenSSL 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41909017/608639), etc.

---

Here's some additional reading you might be interested in:

- [Why does OPENSSL_cleanse look so complex and thread-unsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26433772/608639)
- [Removing OPENSSL_cleanse from OpenSSL-1.0.1r](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35684899/608639)

When functions like `EVP_PKEY_free` and `RSA_free` are called, they eventually end in a call to `OPENSSL_cleanse` before memory is returned to the operating system. In the case of an RSA private key, its called at leats 8 times to wipe the byte arrays associated with `n`, `e`, `d`, `p`, `q`, `dp`, `dq`, and `invq`.

Comment: jww, thanks very much. I checked the source code for openssl 1.0.1u which I'm using. I don't see any OPENSSL_cleanse() call invoked from EVP_PKEY_free(). But I do see lots of OPENSSL_cleanse() called from RSA_free(). Since the rsa key is just a reference from the EVP_PKEY struct memory area, could I safely assume that when I do RSA_free(), it will wipe the rsa key and thus, it also cleaned up the memory of EVP_PKEY struct?

Comment: `EVP_PKEY_free()` eventually calls `EVP_PKEY_free_it()` that uses the `ameth` pointer of the `EVP_PKEY` structure to call the function responsible for cleansing private key data for the particular key type... Abstractions, abstractions everywhere!