# Advantages of SecByteBlock class from Crypto++

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I am using Crypto++ library to decrypt files with AES algorithm in CBC mode. I came across `SecByteBlock` class in [sample code](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_mode) of AES which says

> The key is declared on the stack using a SecByteBlock to ensure the sensitive material is zeroized.

Can someone please explain me when the contents of `SecByteBlock` will get cleared and what advantages this class offer over `char*`.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 7):

> [title] Advantages of SecByteBlock class from Crypto++

The advantage of using `SecByteBlock` is you get the managed buffer with zeroization. Zeroization is often a compliance item. For example, FIPS 140-2 requires it, even at Level 1 validations.

A second, non obvious benefit is the allocator ***does not*** initialize POD memory - it returns a raw block. That makes a lot of sense since you often take a 0-value initialized and then overwrite the contents with data. There's no sense in intializing it, and it saves a lot of time.

You can get `SecBlock` to provide a 0-value initialized block. Here's how to do both:

```
SecByteBlock block1(32);
SecByteBlock block2(NULL, 32);
```

`block1` is 32-bytes in size, uninitialized and its contents will be garbage.

`block2` is also 32-bytes in size, but it uses the `(ptr, size)` overload. The overload will either copy-in the block pointed to by `ptr`, or it will write 0's if its `NULL`.

---

For completeness and reference, a `SecByteBlock` is just a typedef for `SecBlock<byte>`. `SecBlock<T>` is the class of interest, and the library frequently uses `SecBlock<byte>`, `SecBlock<word32>`, `SecBlock<word64>`, etc.

Here's the Doxygen generated manual page for `SecBlock`: [SecBlock< T, A > Class Template Reference](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_sec_block.html). And here's the header file for [secblock.h](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/secblock_8h_source.html) (its a header only implementation).

---

> Can someone please explain me when the contents of `SecByteBlock` will get cleared ...

The contents of `SecByteBlock` are cleared under the obvious case of object destruction. That is, the memory allocated to the `SecBlock` are cleared with a pattern of 0's when the destructor runs.

There's a non obvious case, and that's when `resize` is called to shrink one. In this case, the extra space being returned to the OS is wiped, too.

You can see the wiping in the source code. For example, from [Crypto++ 5.6.4 secblock.h](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/secblock_8h_source.html#l00186):

```
  187     //! \brief Deallocates a block of memory
  188     //! \param ptr the pointer for the allocation
  189     //! \param size the size of the allocation, in elements
  190     //! \details Internally, SecureWipeArray() is called before deallocating the memory.
  191     //!   Once the memory block is wiped or zeroized, AlignedDeallocate() or
  192     //!   UnalignedDeallocate() is called.
  193     //! \details AlignedDeallocate() is used if T_Align16 is true.
  194     //!   UnalignedDeallocate() used if T_Align16 is false.
  195     void deallocate(void *ptr, size_type size)
  196     {
  197         CRYPTOPP_ASSERT((ptr && size) || !(ptr || size));
  198         SecureWipeArray((pointer)ptr, size);
  199 
  200 #if CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16
  201         if (T_Align16 && size*sizeof(T) >= 16)
  202             return AlignedDeallocate(ptr);
  203 #endif
  204 
  205         UnalignedDeallocate(ptr);
  206     }
```

---

> what advantages this class offer over char*.

Well, the `SecBlock<byte>` is a class that manages a buffer. `char*` is just a type and there's not much to it. You have to managed the buffer that the `char*` is pointing to.

You can use something like a `std::string`, but you will not get overflow detection (only `std::vector` is required to check for it) and you will not get zeroization.

With that said, you can do both of these:

- `typdef SecBlock<char> SecCharBlock`
- `typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, AllocatorWithCleanup<char> > secure_string`

The second one is kind of cool. You can do it because [secblock.h](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/secblock_8h_source.html) provides a secure allocator that's compatible with the standard library. `SecBlock<T>` uses the secure allocator internally, and its called an `AllocatiorWithCleanup<T>`.

OpenSSL's wiki page on [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Progams](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) uses a similar allocator to supply a `secure_string` class in their example. OpenSS:'s `zallocator` calls [`OpenSSL_cleanse`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26433772).

From [Crypto++ 5.6.4 secblock.h](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/secblock_8h_source.html#l00186):

```
  141 //! \class AllocatorWithCleanup
  142 //! \brief Allocates a block of memory with cleanup
  143 //! \tparam T class or type
  144 //! \tparam T_Align16 boolean that determines whether allocations should be aligned on 16-byte boundaries
  145 //! \details If T_Align16 is true, then AllocatorWithCleanup calls AlignedAllocate()
  146 //!    for memory allocations. If T_Align16 is false, then AllocatorWithCleanup() calls
  147 //!    UnalignedAllocate() for memory allocations.
  148 //! \details Template parameter T_Align16 is effectively controlled by cryptlib.h and mirrors
  149 //!    CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16. CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16 is often used as the template parameter.
  150 template <class T, bool T_Align16 = false>
  151 class AllocatorWithCleanup : public AllocatorBase<T>
  152 {
  153 public:
  154     CRYPTOPP_INHERIT_ALLOCATOR_TYPES
  155 
  156     //! \brief Allocates a block of memory
  157     //! \param ptr the size of the allocation
  158     //! \param size the size of the allocation, in elements
  159     //! \returns a memory block
  160     //! \throws InvalidArgument
  161     //! \details allocate() first checks the size of the request. If it is non-0
  162     //!   and less than max_size(), then an attempt is made to fulfill the request
  163     //!   using either AlignedAllocate() or UnalignedAllocate().
  164     //! \details AlignedAllocate() is used if T_Align16 is true.
  165     //!   UnalignedAllocate() used if T_Align16 is false.
  166     //! \details This is the C++ *Placement New* operator. ptr is not used, and the function
  167     //!   CRYPTOPP_ASSERTs in Debug builds if ptr is non-NULL.
  168     //! \sa CallNewHandler() for the methods used to recover from a failed
  169     //!   allocation attempt.
  170     //! \note size is the count of elements, and not the number of bytes
  171     pointer allocate(size_type size, const void *ptr = NULL)
  172     {
  173         CRYPTOPP_UNUSED(ptr); CRYPTOPP_ASSERT(ptr == NULL);
  174         this->CheckSize(size);
  175         if (size == 0)
  176             return NULL;
  177 
  178 #if CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16
  179         // TODO: should this need the test 'size*sizeof(T) >= 16'?
  180         if (T_Align16 && size*sizeof(T) >= 16)
  181             return (pointer)AlignedAllocate(size*sizeof(T));
  182 #endif
  183 
  184         return (pointer)UnalignedAllocate(size*sizeof(T));
  185     }
  186     ...
  241 };
```