# Secure, password specific std::string that zeroes itself upon de-allocation

Tags: c++, security, templates, c++11, memory

I found something relevant to the question at [ 1 ] but it is Boost specific due to the age of the post and C++11 having not been matured by that point but otherwise, I'm looking for a secure std::string typedef of the sort below that zeroes itself upon de-allocation.

`typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, SecureStr<char>> string;`

[ 1 ] - [how does one securely clear std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698002/how-does-one-securely-clear-stdstring)

Would anyone know of good examples? The code must also NOT be optimized away on compilation and as such, compromise the security of the application. I know this can be quite the problem without good use of APIs into the O/S and/or compiler.

Comment: You might want to poke around http://crypto.stackexchange.com/. I don't think this is a good question to pose there (check http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to make sure) but you might find some leads.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer in the question you linked doesn't appear to be Boost-specific; it doesn't even mention Boost.  It's a custom allocator for use with `std::basic_string`.

However, it mentions that depending on the implementation of `basic_string`, the allocator may not actually be invoked; `basic_string` may have space to store small strings internally without having to do a separate allocation.  So instantiating `basic_string` with a custom allocator is not enough:  you also need to zero the memory of the string object itself, in addition to any buffers it may have allocated.

One way to do that would be to use a `unique_ptr` constructed with a custom deleter function.  `unique_ptr` doesn't deal with allocators directly, but you could allocate storage for a `basic_string` using your custom allocator, then construct a `unique_ptr` to it with a deleter that also delegates to the custom allocator.

BTW, you're just looking at zeroing memory when you're done with it, but another thing to be concerned about is the possibility that the sensitive data gets paged out to disk.  Operating systems provide (non-portable) APIs for locking small amounts of data in RAM so it won't be paged out; you might want to take advantage of those features in your custom allocator.

Comment: Excuse me if this is wrong, as templates are a brand new concept to me, but would this work? http://pastebin.com/Jr7NLkVh

Comment: EDIT: I posted in-complete code x_x Here's the correct code: http://pastebin.com/aQfAaGx7