# Is there a good C++ implementation of Secure Strings

Tags: c++, string, security

I'm wondering, if there is some good implementation of some kind of counterpart of the C# SecureString class?

I already found some stuff, using XOR operations on bytes, but that seems too vulnerable to me.

Comment: [crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/) and [botan](https://botan.randombit.net/) both have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least the C++ crypto libraries [crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/) and [botan](https://botan.randombit.net/) both provide helpers for 'secure strings'. There are probably more libraries with that functionality out there.

In crypto++ you could for example use:

```
#include <string>
#include <cryptopp/secblock.h>

using secure_string = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<char>>;
```

Any `secure_string` you create afterwards, (which are declared basically just like any other regular `std::string`, i.e. `secure_string str("secret");`), will (in practise*) get their memory zeroed out on destruction.

Botan has a [secure allocator](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/secmem_8h_source.html), that you would use the same way the crypto++ allocator is used in the previous example, which also zeroes out the memory on free.

There is also a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698002/how-does-one-securely-clear-stdstring) on SO, that covers the topic on how you would implement your own secure allocator, if, for some reason, you don't want to include external libraries.

---

* `std::string` wasn't designed with security in mind. I recommend reading the linked answer and related material on how and why it may fail.