# How can I delete dynamic array pointer correctly

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ delete - It deletes my objects but I can still access the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930459/c-delete-it-deletes-my-objects-but-i-can-still-access-the-data)
>   [Why doesn't delete destroy anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280410/why-doesnt-delete-destroy-anything)

I've Created dynamic array, and I added values ​​to the values ​​of the array like that.

```
int *pArr;
pArr = new int[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   pArr[i] = i+2;
}

delete[] pArr;  

// After deletion I can find the value of the array items.
cout << pArr[5] << endl;
```

As you see in the code above and in the last line, I can output the fifth element in the array without any problem .
With that supposed to be the array has been removed.

Comment: You misunderstand what `delete` means. The memory isn't GONE, you've just told C++ that you aren't going to use it anymore. Then you broke your promise.

Comment: +1 for giving isnight why c and c++ are not for children.

Comment: [Your bible wasn't touched.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/596781)

Comment: @Fred Larson: I think your answer is right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the memory can be used again, consider this expansion of your code:

```
int *pArr;
pArr = new int[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       pArr[i] = i+2;
}

delete[] pArr;

int *pArr2;
pArr2 = new int[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       pArr2[i] = (2*i)+2;
}

cout << pArr[5] << endl;
```

That prints out `12` for me. i.e. the value from `pArr2[5]` actually. Or at least I should say it does for my machine with my specific compiler & version, etc. As others have pointed out it is *undefined behaviour*. But hopefully my example shows you at least one kind of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Once you `delete[]` the array and still try to access the elements of the array it is Undefined Behavior and any behavior is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this may work, but is not *guaranteed* to work. Delete [] only invalidates the memory but does not zero it. The memory you are referencing is invalidate at this point. So don't do it :)